# meaning of numpy.zeros((0,x))

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I got the code:

```
def bbox_transform_inv(boxes, deltas):

   if boxes.shape[0] == 0:
       return np.zeros((0, deltas.shape[1]), dtype=deltas.dtype)
```

it return a array and the row of array is 0. 
what's meaning of the array?

the code is from https://github.com/endernewton/tf-faster-rcnn/blob/master/lib/model/bbox_transform.py
in #35-37

Comment: Well you created an array of size 0 (0 × 5 = 0). That array has no elements you could set.

Comment: Please include the desired result. The answers are currently just guessing what you intended. You may get better answers if we know what you wanted to do.

Comment: Try `a=numpy.zeros((3))` and `a[1]=3`.

Comment: sorry, i didn't describe it clearly just now...

Comment: I edited it again...several mins ago

Comment: Your edit changes the question substantially.  Originally you tried to set an element of the array.  I doubt if any code that uses the array returned by this function tries to do that.  A size 0 dimension is allowed, but not every every operation makes sense with such an array.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean to create an array with one line and 5 columns?

```
a = np.zeros((1,5))
a[0,1] = 3
```

```
array([[0., 3., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = numpy.zeros((0,3))
```

Means that you will receive a matrix (a list of lists) with 0 rows and 3 columns. Obviously  that means that a[1] (2nd row of the matrix with index=1) doesn't make any sense, because you have 0 rows now

```
a = numpy.zeros((3,3))
```

will give you the matrix of 3x3 and a[1] will make sense now

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want to get is `a = np.zeros((1,3))`,the out is `array([[0., 0., 0.]])`
then `a[0][1] = 3` the out is `array([[0., 3., 0.]])`

if you want is `a = np.zeros((3,1))`, the out is `array([[0.],[0.],[0.]])`
then `a[1][0] = 3` the out is `array([[0.],[3.],[0.]])`